# Плавное увеличение/уменьшение внутренней картинки при наведении на родителя

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Есть таблица в которую вставлены разные по размеру картинки, при наведении на строку, картинка хоранящаяся в одной из ее ячеек должна увеличиваться.

```js
$('.table-about tr')
  .mouseover(function() {  $(this).find("img").css("width", parseInt($(this).find("img").css('width'))*1.1)})
  .mouseleave(function() {  $(this).find("img").css("width", parseInt($(this).find("img").css('width'))/1.1)})
```

```css
.table-about td img{
transition: 800ms;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
height: auto!important;
}
.table-about td {
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" class="table-about" style="width:100%"><tbody><tr><td style="height: 195px; width: 284px;"><img alt="" src="http://bm.let120.net//ckfinder/userfiles/images/comp1.png" style="height: 162px; width: 263.636px;"></td>
   <td>&nbsp;</td>
   <td>- NTRCN NEN ,ELTN</td>
  </tr><tr><td style="height: 170px; width: 250px;"><img alt="" src="http://bm.let120.net//ckfinder/userfiles/images/comp2.png" style="height: 178px; width: 265.455px;"></td>
   <td>&nbsp;</td>
   <td>- F 'NJ TOT JLBY NTRCN DJN NFRJQ DJN JY</td>
  </tr><tr><td style="height: 120px; width: 200px;"><img alt="" src="http://bm.let120.net//ckfinder/userfiles/images/comp3.png" style="height: 191px; width: 222.727px;"></td>
   <td>&nbsp;</td>
   <td>-"NJ GHBVTH GHBVTH GHBVTH</td>
  </tr></tbody></table>
```

Попробовал написать скрипт который помогает это реализовать, но если водить быстро мышью картинки начинают бесконтрольно увеличиваться или уменьшаться. 
Я не против если будет написано обычными стилями, но не нашел нормально способа, так как изначально все картинки имеют разный размер, и предварительно подготовить их нет возможности

Comment: Помогло данное решение?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно без `js`, просто добавьте `img:hover` в котором будите задавать нужное увеличение. 
***Пример:***

```css
.table-about td img{
transition: 800ms;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
height: auto!important;
}
.table-about td {
    position: relative;
}
.table-about td:hover img{
transform: scale(1.1); 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" class="table-about" style="width:100%">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="height: 195px; width: 284px;"><img alt="" src="http://bm.let120.net//ckfinder/userfiles/images/comp1.png" style="height: 162px; width: 263.636px;"></td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>- NTRCN NEN ,ELTN</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="height: 170px; width: 250px;"><img alt="" src="http://bm.let120.net//ckfinder/userfiles/images/comp2.png" style="height: 178px; width: 265.455px;"></td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>- F 'NJ TOT JLBY NTRCN DJN NFRJQ DJN JY</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="height: 120px; width: 200px;"><img alt="" src="http://bm.let120.net//ckfinder/userfiles/images/comp3.png" style="height: 191px; width: 222.727px;"></td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>-"NJ GHBVTH GHBVTH GHBVTH</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```